# How to change the indentation of new added script tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i'm using the following code to insert new script with content to HTML file,
Currently the following code is working and the new script is inserted after the first existing script, the problem is the content is not indent

e.g. this is the output of the new added script(as you can see its in one line)

```
<script>  var keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];  var filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];          </script>
```

I want to change it to be indented like following:

1. the second added open script tag will be inserted line **after** the **closing** tag of the first script
2. the vars should be inserted one after other to be like this

> ```
> <script>
> var keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];
> var filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];
> </script>
> ```

How I can do that ? I belive I need to add the /n but not sure where is the best way to insert it...

https://jsfiddle.net/k32ntkr8/

**This is the JS code**

```
btn.onclick = function(e){
debugger;
 var innerhtml = [
        '  var keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];',
        '  var filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];          '
    ].join('');

    var html = process(input.defaultValue,innerhtml);
    output.value = html;

}


function process(html,innerhtml) {
    var escapedHTML = html
        .replace(/body/g, 'body$')
        .replace(/head/g, 'head$');
    sandbox.innerHTML = escapedHTML;

    var script = sandbox.querySelectorAll('#app-ux-bootstrap')[0];

    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.innerText = innerhtml;
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, script.nextSibling);

    var unescapedHTML = sandbox.innerHTML
        .replace(/body\$/g, 'body')
        .replace(/head\$/g, 'head')
        .replace(/&quot;/g, "'");

    return (
        '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>' +
        unescapedHTML +
        '</html>'
    );

};
```

How it can be done? please suggest ,the answer below doesn't help much...
if I can improve this question somehow please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, but why would you want to do that? Most of the time, when people finish their code, they minimize it to have smaller files, not opposite... I'm just curious...

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic - correct during the build the minifying the file but I need to show this file before in some editor ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you change your onclick handler to this

```
btn.onclick = function(e){
debugger;
 var innerhtml = [
        '',
        '        <script>',
        '           var keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];',
        '           var filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];         ',
        '        <\/script>'
    ].join('\n');

    var html = process(input.defaultValue,innerhtml);
    output.value = html;

}
```

And change the lines of `process` that populate the script to this

```
 var script = sandbox.querySelectorAll('#app-ux-bootstrap')[0];
 script.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', innerhtml);
```

You should get this output

```
<head>
  <script>
    var keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];
    var filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];         
  </script>
...
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks but where exactly its better to do it?

Comment: You can do it where you do it now but instead of joining with an empty string join with the new line

Comment: I dont want it inside the var declaration(innerhtml) just after and in addition I need that the new inserted script tag will be under the first closing script tag   ? can you update please the jsFiddle if it works for you?Thanks sir

Comment: @gabesoft - can you assist please ,do you have any idea how to handle this? thank you sir!

Comment: Updated the answer and the jsFiddle

Comment: @gabesoft - Thanks but I try the jsFiddle and it doesnt work still the code doesnt indented ,maybe you send the wrong fiddle ?thanks sir

Comment: @gabesoft - sorry my fault :( 1+ , assume I got this innerHtml as string without the join how can I indent it as the result you provide? this var can be any string...Thank you very much sir

Comment: If you don't generate that string then you'll have to insert new lines somehow. Maybe with a regex ``innerhtml = innerhtml.replace(/;/g, ';\n')``

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var innerhtml = [
    '\tvar keyOfFilesArray = Object.keys(data)[0];',
    '\tvar filesArray = data[keyOfFilesArray];'
].join("\n");

var script_code = '<script>\n' + innerhtml + '\n<\/script>';
```

Then just insert the script_code variable wherever you want it to appear on the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/e72c17zg/1/

Comment: Can it be generic , I mean assume that I get any string inside this inner html  without the join and the '\t' how can I create it as the result that you provide ?thanks sir